# JavaScript: Executing tracking code dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tracking, wizard

I've got a wizard that collects data from `Step 1` to `Step 6`. Now, depending on what data is collected, the final messaging and available resources change ... but what I'd like to figure out is the best way to execute some JavaScript depending on the results ... but without a page load, I don't know how to accomplish this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://asd.mydomain.com/a.aspx?o=5969&st=1000&**result=0002**"></script>
```

As you can see, the `result` param needs to change depending on what the user selects during the wizard ... but since this block is rendered when the page loads, how do I execute the call dynamically? jQuery AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many choices:

Dynamically add the script tag

```
function pingValue (value) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://asd.example.com/a.aspx?o=5969&st=1000&result=" + value;
    document.body.appendChild("script");
}
```

Just call it with an image

```
function pingValue (value) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://asd.example.com/a.aspx?o=5969&st=1000&result=" + value;
}
```

Override the existing element

```
function pingValue (value) {
    var script = document.getElementById("myScriptId");
    script.src = "https://asd.example.com/a.aspx?o=5969&st=1000&result=" + value;
}
```

Make an Ajax call is another or jQuery has [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)